# Which blender version you recommend for absolute beginners?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm working on Unity Engine for years now and decided to learn how to use blender.

Which blender version have many good tutorials on YouTube? Should I start with 2.8 or 3.0.. or 3.2?

Already googled it and I found that "V2.8" but that answer was 2 years ago : [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-we-are-a-complete-beginner-in-Blender-do-we-have-to-learn-previous-versions-or-can-we-continue-from-the-latest-versions)

**So, which version you highly recommend now?** *Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Well, what is your goal in Blender? If you want to learn the basic functions like moving, rotating, scaling things, extruding and beveling etc. it mostly doesn't matter. If you see people creating fancy stuff with _Geometry Nodes_ and want to do the same, 2.8 is absolute nonsense since those nodes didn't exist back then. It makes sense to use recent versions because chances are you have all new features and bugs from older versions are removed. But to start with the basics, the version doesn't matter much. For the most part it won't even matter if your version is different from the tutorial.

Comment: @quellenform is right !
Don't be afraid when on a youtube tutorial, the author say he is using Blender 2.xx or something like this, 99.9% of the time, in the latest stable version you'll be able to achieve the same thing, maybe with a different path. I recommend to always use the internal search option of blender to see what it is possible to achieve depending on what you're doing (modeling, texturing, etc...) and be sure to always refer to the official documentation.
If you're used to Unity, you already know a lot of technical vocabulary, that is the hard point for a very beginner in 3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the possibility to decide freely and some technical circumstances do not force you to a certain version, the following basic rule always applies in the area of software:

**Always use the latest stable version offered by the developer!**

The probability that you will get the most support, the best functionality and the fewest bugs is the highest.

Comment: I would add that if you're in a really time, cost or team constrained environment and you don't care or can work around missing the latest features it is recommended to use the latest LTS release instead of the latest stable release.

Comment: @Gorgious That is absolutely correct! However, I assume that an "absolute beginner" is unlikely to be involved in such a process/workflow.

Comment: @quellenform Alright thanks a lot! I will start with V3.2.2 (sadly there are few tutorials but hopefully V3.0 & V3.2 & 3.2.2 UI are the same in order not to get lost while watching V3.0/V3.2 tutorials.

Comment: @DaSoliman Everything below 3.0 is outdated anyway regarding *Geometry Nodes*, so tutorials don't make much sense. But above version 3.0 there are essentially no dramatic differences (mainly bugfixes). There are always some new nodes added to the versions, but here on BSE you can find very good help. Regarding tutorials, I would basically look at everything above version 3.1 more closely.